# morris charts showing code under chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

Hi guys this might be a really silly question but i have looked everywhere and can't find a solution.

I am using Morris charts and they are working fine.

The problem is that under the chart they display the data for the chart which i don't want visible

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.2/raphael-min.js"></script>
  <script src="../morris.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r224/prettify.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/example.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/example.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r224/prettify.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../morris.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Stacked Bars chart</h1>
<div id="graph"></div>
<pre id="code" class="prettyprint linenums">
// Use Morris.Bar
Morris.Bar({
  element: 'graph',
  data: [
{x: '2011 Q1', y: 3, z: 2, a: 3},
{x: '2011 Q2', y: 2, z: null, a: 1},
{x: '2011 Q3', y: 0, z: 2, a: 4},
{x: '2011 Q4', y: 2, z: 4, a: 3}
  ],
  xkey: 'x',
  ykeys: ['y', 'z', 'a'],
  labels: ['Y', 'Z', 'A'],
  stacked: true
});
</pre>
</body>
```

everything inside the  tags is displayed below the chart in a box.

If you remove the "pretty print linenums" class this removes the box however if you remove the  tag the code is still displayed but there is no chart.

Any anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Try to replace `<pre id="code" class="prettyprint linenums">`by `<script>` and `</pre>` by `</script>`... For fun.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick 

Comment: It's not a "trick". Its the right tags where to put the morris data definition. `<pre>` and `</pre>` is a set of text format tag. I assume your problem is resolved... Totally ?

Comment: Sorry I ment did the trick as in that solved the problem.

Comment: Okay then. In order to remove this question from the "unanswered" list... You can answer yourself... Or remove the question. It would be easy points for me to answer ... But lolll It's too easy now ! ;)

Comment: And dont take it personnal like if I was laughting at you... What you don't know is HARD to find. But this is easy for most programmers... I'm surprised anyone answered it in like... 20 seconds.

Comment: No problem. I tried to answer it but said I did not meet quality standards. Please feel free to answer if it helps you in any way

Comment: ?? Really ? You can't answer yourself on this?

Comment: I'm upvoting you in that case ;) And sorry if I've hurt you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... An easy one.

Like I said in comments... Any knowledge one don't have may be hard to find.
No blame on you.
So here, the question was REALLY simple... For someone who knows.

Just replace `<pre id="code" class="prettyprint linenums">` by `<script>`
and `</pre>` by `</script>`.

;)

`<pre>` and `</pre>` is a set of text format tag that isn't equivalent to the `<script>` tags.